# How to do SSL on a domain only accessable through current network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, terminal, openssl

### To Set The Context

I am using `Node.JS` on Mac OS. I am hosting a server on the network domain `quicvo.local`. I am curious how to have proper SSL without the browser giving a warning saying something along the lines of:

> This website may be impersonating "quicvo.local" to steal your personal or financial information. You should go back to the previous page.

Of course, the user can *trust* this website on their device, but that is not ideal and makes my website look very sketchy. I have tried using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), but it doesn't allow domains in the `.local` extension. I figured that someone else has tried this and succeeded, so I thought I might ask. I have gotten this far with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) by self-signing a certificate.

---

### Here Is What I Have Tried

**OpenSSL Command Line In Terminal At `./security/` Context**

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

**Node.JS `require('https').createServer` Options**

```js
const security = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./security/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/server.cert')
};
```

Comment: You’ll probably have a hard time getting *any* already trusted authority to sign a certificate for .local, so you *will* have to explicitly trust that certificate and/or install your own self-signed root certificate on all networked machines.

Comment: @deceze, Okay thanks for letting me know